# People API getting error when Age Ranges is specified

Tags: google-apps-script, contacts, google-people-api

I have tried with People contact create API but I am getting error. I believe the ENUM data is correct

This happens for Skills and Age ranges

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "person.age_ranges is a read only field.",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}

People.People.createContact(  {"skills": [
    {
      "value": "Playing"
    }
  ],
  "ageRanges": [
    {
      "ageRange": "TWENTY_ONE_OR_OLDER"
    }
  ],

})
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Answer:

*The `ageRanges[]` field can not be set as it is a read-only field.*

#### More Information:

As per the Person resource in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people#Person):

> | `ageRanges[]` | `object` ([`AgeRangeType`](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people#Person.AgeRangeType)) |
> | --- | --- |
> |  | Output only. The person's age ranges |

As this is an output only value, it can not be written to by calling `people.createContact`.